# windbg, cdb unable to query for remote debugging server

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging

I have no trouble running dbgsrv on one machine, and then from another machine using cbb to attach to the remote session with

cdb -premote tcp:server=*ipaddress*,port=*port*  *process*

However for some reason I can't make

cdb -QR *ipaddress*

work to show the server. Even with the server running on the same machine, firewall off, running

cdb -QR 127.0.0.1

returns

Unable to query 127.0.0.1

Similarly windbg > Connect To Remote Stub > Browse also fails to return anything.

Also, while I can connect to the remote session using

windbg -premote tcp:server=*ipaddress*,port=*port*   *process*

I can't use windbgs "Connect to remote stub" to connect to the very same session using connection string

tcp:server=*ipaddress*,port=*port*   *process*

Any idea what is causing me to not be able to query for server sessions? Also why can I connect from the command line, but not from within windbg using Connect To Remote Stub?

P.S. This should probably also be tagged dbgsrv, but there is no such tag.

P.P.S. The reason I want to use dbgsrv rather than .server command is that I want to resolve symbols and source on my local machine.

Comment: According the documentation: For a debugging server to be discoverable, it must be activated with elevated privileges. Did you run DbgSrv as administrator? Other than that (which was not mentioned) I'd say you did everything right and understood what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `cdb -QR \\127.0.0.1`
When using *windbg > Connect To Remote Stub > Browse*, Enter the IP address of the computer you want to browse in the Machine field before clicking on Refresh

Comment: I did enter the IP address I wanted to browse in the machine field before clicking refresh. :)  I tried your syntax suggestion, but I'm afraid it just gave the same result. I don't think it is a syntax error I'm facing in that command. Thanks for taking the time to make your suggestions though.

Comment: According the documentation the `\\` are optional.